# How to remove leading space in this string in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, string, replace, google-bigquery

I have some values in my data that have leading spaces in the string character. Looks like when the data was inputted someone left a space by mistake. How can I remove that leading space? I would assume it would be a regex solution.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Bigquery` `TRIM` function to remove spaces on a `STRING` value, example :

```sql
SELECT
  '  Original String_',
TRIM('  Original String_') AS trimmed,
LTRIM('  Original String_') AS left_trim,
RTRIM('  Original String_', "_") AS right_trim
```

- TRIM removes left and right spaces
- LTRIM removes only left spaces
- RTRIM removes only right spaces

Comment: Quick correction needed in above: TRIM does not remove "all" spaces: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#trim It only removes front and back spaces.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, it was not correctly formulated, I added a correction on my answer.